# User specific tracks search using soundcloud api

Tags: soundcloud

Is there a way to make user specific track search using the soundcloud api? This is a sample api call url that returns various track results from other all of soundcloud, which is not the desired result.

https://api.soundcloud.com/users/CLIENT_USER_NAME/tracks?q=SEARCH_TERM&client_id=CLIENT_ID

Answer (score 1):

You can use SC.get to return all of a particular user's tracks, e.g.

```
SC.get('/users/id/tracks', function(tracks){
    // Do stuff
});
```

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#users

To get the user id, you can use resolve:

http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#resolve

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot search a specific user's tracks. The documentation is wrong in this case.